# Spring roo - NonRelational DB support

Tags: java, database, spring-roo, objectdb

I'm looking for an nonRelational DB implementation (objectDB, or XMLDB) Could somebody recommend some working/tested sollution, how store objects/XMLdata in a DB?

Answer (score 0):

I recieved additional info, that spring roo stores JDO by itself, using datastore/datanucleus, and no other DB is required.

or 2nd option -> [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) +  Morphia
or 3rd option -> www.db4o.com

Answer (score 0):

For xml documents persistence as a primary requirement, the best option is to use native XML database like [Exist](http://exist-db.org/). It is using Hierarchical data model afaik and xml document persistence is really simple with it.